# Web Scrape PHP CSS Style

Tags: php, web-scraping

```
<style type=text/css>
    span.show{
        display: inline;
    }
    span.showy{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

I am trying to scrape a website that has something very similar to the above style within the `<head>` tag. The show and showy tag changes dynamically every time the website is loaded.

They have spans something like this:

```
<div>
    <span class=show>1</span>
    <span class=showy>2</span>
    <span class=show>3</span>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to scrape the class where this is true: `display: inline`. How is that does with PHP?

EDIT:
If you load the page right now, the CSS tags may be hello1 and hello2. If you refresh the page, they may be changed from hello1/hello2 to hello10/hello20.

I have to find out which classname has the display:inline.

Comment: "The show and showy tag changes dynamically every time the website is loaded." the class names change or they switch? That's not clear

Comment: @hppycoder i updated question, hopfully that makes it clear. Those class names change on every page load... i need to find out which class is inline, which isnt.

Comment: I'm not sure that makes it clearer. Now we've gone from class names `show|showy` to `helloXX`. Which is it? Perhaps more code would be helpful

Comment: Thats is the point @Steven. The class names change on every page load. span.hello may have inline. if you reload the page, that class name is changed dynamically to span.hello2.... my goal is to find the class name that has display:inline;

Comment: Is there only ever one class on the page defined as inline? or is it a utility class that solely consists of the `display` property? Does it always start `span.`?

Comment: yes. there is only 1 second in the website that have the <style> tag. yes, it is always span. @Steven

Comment: You could look into the [Symfony DOMCrawler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#expression-evaluation) which has an express evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

**Method**

1. Use the `preg_match` function to find the utility class which only contains the `display: inline;` descriptor. Use capture groups to isolate.
2. Use `preg_match_all` to scrape the data. Use capture groups to capture data between tags.

**Code**

```
$webPage = <<<EOT
<style type=text/css>
    span.show{
        display: inline;
    }
    span.showy{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <span class=show>1</span>
    <span class=showy>2</span>
    <span class=show>3</span>
</div>
EOT;

// Find the class with the property `display: inline`
preg_match("#span.(\w+){\s*display: inline;\s*}#", $webPage, $matches);

// Scrape the data
preg_match_all("#<span class={$matches[1]}>([^<]*)</span>#", $webPage, $scrapedData);

print_r($scrapedData);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <span class=show>1</span>
            [1] => <span class=show>3</span>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: I'd just note that there's a good chance this happens client-side in a way PHP isn't going to be able to see.